# Unable to add task to todo list

Tags: python, html, flask

When I try to add a new task on my website I get the message "POST /templates/todo" Error (404): "Not found" and cannot find what is wrong with the code. Can anyone help me figure it out? It was done on cs50ide software. If anyone could also inform me whether I am able to create a functioning link for my website (I use python, flask, html and css) I would be very grateful! Thank you so much (the weird thing is that it was working before...)

**Code for add.html**

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/static/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>
          Add a New Task :)
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class = "aligncenter">
            <img class = "img1" src = "/static/images/logocarol.jpg" alt = "Logo" height = "200" width = "550"/>    
        </h1>
        <h1 class="centergeneral fontsize">
            Add any goals, dreams and aspirations you might have here:
        </h1>
        <form class="aligncenter" action="todo" method="post"> 
            <input id="task" name="task" type="text" placeholder="New Task :)">   
            <input id="submit" type="submit" disabled>
        </form>
        <script>
            document.querySelector('#task').onkeyup = function(){
                if (document.querySelector('#task').value === ''){
                    document.querySelector('#submit').disabled = true;
                } else {
                     document.querySelector('#submit').disabled = false;
                }
            }
        </script>
        
        <form action="/">
            <button type="submit" id = "back" class="btn btn-info margin"> BACK TO HOMEPAGE </button> <br> <br>
        </form>
        <form action="todo">
            <button type="submit" id = "back" class="btn btn-outline-info margin"> BACK TO TO DO LIST </button> <br> <br>
        </form>
    </body>
```

**Code for todo.html:**

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/static/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>
          To Do List! :)
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class = "aligncenter">
            <img class = "img1" src = "/static/images/logocarol.jpg" alt = "Logo" height = "200" width = "550"/>    
        </h1>
        <h1 class="fonts centergeneral"> To Do List </h1>
        <h2 class="fs-4 centergeneral"> What I Want to Achieve: </h2> <br>
        <ul class="listcenter">
            <script>
            {%for todo in todos%}
                <li> {{ todo }} <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1"> </li> 
            {%endfor%}
            </script>
        </ul>
        
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info margin" href = "add"> Add a New Task</a>
        <a class="btn btn-outline-info" href = "clear"> Clear Tasks </a> <br>
        <div class="backbuttons">
        <form action = "/">
            <button type="submit" id = "back" class="btn btn-info"> BACK TO HOMEPAGE </button> <br> <br>
        </form>
        </div>
```

**Code for application.py**

````
from flask_session import Session
from cs50 import SQL

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
Session(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/f1inschools')
def f1():
    return render_template('f1inschools.html')
    
@app.route('/pdwt')
def pdwt():
    return render_template('pdwt.html')
    
@app.route('/pros')
def pros():
    return render_template('pros.html')
    
@app.route('/bookrecommendations')
def books():
    return render_template('bookrecs.html')
    
@app.route('/todolist')
def todo():
    if "todos" not in session:
        session["todos"] = []
    return render_template('todo.html', todos=session["todos"])
        
@app.route('/clear')
def clear():
    return redirect("/todolist")
    session["todos"] = []
        
@app.route('/add', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def add():
    if request.method == "GET":
       return render_template("add.html")
    else:
        todo = request.form.get("task")
        session["todos"].append(todo)
        return redirect("/todolist")```
````

Comment: You are submitting the form on wrong url.

Answer (score 0):

You're submitting the form on wrong URL.

```
<form class="aligncenter" action="todo" method="post">
```

Should be,

```
<form class="aligncenter" action="/todolist" method="post">
```

Comment: I changed it and it still does not work...

Answer (score 0):

If all your templates are stored in the template folder, include this change in `app`.

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="templates", static_folder='static')
```

You've also got to change the url in which the form is being submitted to,
to `/todolist` and also make this change in `application.py`

```
@app.route('/todolist', methods=["GET", "POST"])
```

**add.html**

```
        <form class="aligncenter" action="/todolist" method="POST"> 
            <input id="task" name="task" type="text" placeholder="New Task :)">   
            <input id="submit" type="submit" disabled>
        </form>
```

Comment: tried this but still getting a "POST /todolist" Error (404): "Not found" error...

Comment: You have to change the URL in the form in add.html too. I have updated the code. It is working for me.

Comment: I did it exactly like you did but it's still not working for me. Do you know what might be causing the issue?

Comment: I'm not sure really. I was able to add a task and it redirected me to `/todolist`. You must have a typo somewhere.

Comment: Is my "for" statement correct? and also, the change you told me to do in application.py is to the //todolist function right? the add function is kept the same. Thank you so much for your support

Comment: When I tried out your code, I wasn't able to submit the form and it gave the error you mentioned. The changes I made in `add.html` made it able to access the page properly. You don't need the `<script>` tag enclosing the `for` statement.